# Removing Unnecessary Services & Packages in a MySQL Ubuntu 12.04 Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, security, ubuntu-12.04

As part of hardening a **standalone/dedicated** MySQL 5.6 server running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, unnecessary services and packages will have to be removed.

For a server that is serving only as a MySQL server, what services and packages should we remove? Is there a list of services/packages that we can use?

Here's a list of services running (?). Which are the ones them look like they could be stopped and their packages removed?

```
[ ? ]  acpid
[ ? ]  anacron
[ ? ]  atd
[ - ]  bootlogd
[ ? ]  console-setup
[ ? ]  cron
[ ? ]  cryptdisks
[ ? ]  cryptdisks-early
[ ? ]  cryptdisks-enable
[ ? ]  cryptdisks-udev
[ ? ]  dbus
[ ? ]  dmesg
[ - ]  grub-common
[ ? ]  hostname
[ ? ]  hwclock
[ ? ]  hwclock-save
[ - ]  keymap.sh
[ ? ]  killprocs
[ ? ]  module-init-tools
[ ? ]  network-interface
[ ? ]  network-interface-container
[ ? ]  network-interface-security
[ ? ]  networking
[ ? ]  ondemand
[ ? ]  passwd
[ ? ]  plymouth
[ ? ]  plymouth-log
[ ? ]  plymouth-ready
[ ? ]  plymouth-splash
[ ? ]  plymouth-stop
[ ? ]  plymouth-upstart-bridge
[ ? ]  procps
[ ? ]  rc.digitalocean
[ ? ]  rc.local
[ ? ]  resolvconf
[ - ]  rsync
[ ? ]  rsyslog
[ ? ]  sendsigs
[ ? ]  setvtrgb
[ + ]  ssh
[ - ]  stop-bootlogd
[ - ]  stop-bootlogd-single
[ ? ]  sudo
[ ? ]  udev
[ ? ]  udev-fallback-graphics
[ ? ]  udev-finish
[ ? ]  udevmonitor
[ ? ]  udevtrigger
[ ? ]  umountfs
[ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
[ ? ]  umountroot
[ - ]  unattended-upgrades
[ - ]  urandom
```

Comment: Closely related: [Which services to disable on a CentOs 5.8 web/database server?](http://serverfault.com/q/441324/126632)

Comment: Is there a business reason to start with Ubuntu Server, instead of.... say.... CentOS? Personal Biases aside, you and me both.

Comment: @MDMoore313 Probably not. The developers just "want" it, usually. One problem with Ubuntu here is that it enables everything by default, has no firewall, ... that's two problems.

Comment: Please do not cross-post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818887/removing-unnecessary-services-packages-in-a-mysql-ubuntu-12-04-server - also, I can only echo the comment in the other question: `Work out what ones are not required. And then do your job`

Comment: I dont think its similar to `Tips for Securing a LAMP Server`. The server is a dedicated MySQL server and accepts connections from only the app server.

Comment: OK, so you _say_ it's a dedicated server. What's with all the Digital Ocean stuff, then?

Comment: By dedicated, I meant to say the main purpose of the server is to act as a MySQL server, if a public facing web server or reverse proxy like Apache/nginx/Passenger is used it will be on a separate machine/instance.

Comment: Well, you have nothing left to do but actually install the service.

Answer (score 0):

This is already minimalist. You have ssh enabled and that's about it. Almost everything else is startup and shutdown tasks.

One thing you *should* enable is `acpid`. Without this, you may not be able to shutdown or reboot your droplet from Digital Ocean's control panel. (Or, on a physical server, the power button will not perform a graceful shutdown but instead hard power off the machine.)