# IPTABLES - IP Restricted Port Forwarding for RDP

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, port-forwarding

I can't find an answered question for this problem.

I have about 7 ranges of IP address i would like to allow to RDP(port 3389) to a a server within my network.

My main router uses iptables and i cant seem to figure out what the right combination is ...

this is the closest i've gotten which doesnt seem to work

```
iptables -t filter -l FORWARD -d 192.168.x.xx -p tcp -m iprange --src-range xx.xxx.xxx.100-xxx.xxx.xxx.200 --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
```

What is the correct way of doing this...

**UPDATE:**

I have found a solution to the problem. Please see answer below for my solution

Comment: Duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/6989/iptables-multiple-source-ips . There's everything you need.

Comment: This doesnt answer any of my question... how is it a duplicate? I've already seen that answer....

Comment: There you are: you cannot use  `-m iprange --src-range` for that. `iptables v1.4.21: iprange: option "--src-range" can only be used once. `

Comment: But i do not want to allow the whole /24 block ... and i only want to forward one protocol

Comment: You don't have to: `iptables -t filter -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/28,192.168.1.8/31,192.168.1.10/32 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT`, but chains are better for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41743/discussion-between-mike-pengelly-and-michal-sokolowski).

Answer (score 0):

So this is the definitive answer i was looking for.

You first need to set NAT (prerouting) rule to redirect the traffic to the correct server/computer. Done like this...

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s yy.yy.yy.0/24 --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.xx:3389
```

Then you need a Filter (FORWARD) Rule to allow the traffic to flow to the destination like this...

```
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -s yy.yy.yy.0/24 -d 192.168.1.xx -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
```

Note:

*yy.yy.yy.0/24* is the IP block you would like to allow ... See https://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html for help with subnets.

*192.168.1.xx* is the destination server in your local LAN.

Comment: Ipset make whitelisting and blacklisting much easier especially for large number of up addresses.